# What happens at the boundary of the disk of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I got stuck in solving a question of power series in complex analysis in Conway's exercise. Which is as follows $:$

> Find the radius of convergence of the power series $:$
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n} {n} z^{n(n+1)}.$$
>
> What happens at the boundary of the disk of convergence?

I found that the radius of convergence to be $1$ and hence the disk of convergence is $|z|=1$. Now I found at $z=1,-1$ the series is convergent by Leibnitz test. Now how can I check the point of convergence (if any) in the disk of convergence other than $1$ and $-1$. I tried with Dirchilet's test. But I couldn't actually figure out how is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} z^{k(k+1)}$$ look like? Is it bounded for arbitrary $n$ for all $z$ on $\partial B(0;1)$ except at $1$ and $-1$?

Please give me some suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not hard to see that it also converges when $z=\pm i$.

Comment: Yes.It's correct.But for all other points?

Comment: Use partial summation to make $\sum_{m \le n} \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m} = \log 2+\frac{1+(-1)^{n+1}}{n}+\mathcal{O}(n^{-2})$ appear