# What can be said about the convergence on $|z|=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> I already found the radius of convergence of the power series $:$
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n} {n} z^{n(n+1)}.$$
>
> What happens at the boundary of disk of convergence?

I found that the radius of convergence to be $1$ and hence the disk of convergence is $|z|<1$. Now I found at $z=1$ the series converges.

Now how can I proceed?
Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^n} {n}.$$ Which is convergent by Leibnitz's test.

Comment: For the real arguments $\pm 1$, yes.  But this is a complex domain problem.

Comment: A ring of doom?  I think there might be infinitely may singularities on the boundary.

Comment: Exact duplicate of question asked by other user 6 hours ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415413/what-happens-at-the-boundary-of-the-disk-of-convergence#comment4988856_2415413

Answer (score 1):

"I found that the radius of convergence to be 1 and hence the disk of convergence is $|z|=1$"
  That's not a disk, it is a circle.  I presume you mean that convergence is clear for $|z|< 1$. What happens on the circle $|z|= 1$ depends on the precise value of $z$.

"Now I found at $z=1$ the series converges."
 Okay, the series in question is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}z^{n(n+1)}$.  At z= 1 that is the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ which converges because $\frac{1}{n}$ is descending.

Any point on the circle $|z|= 1$ can be written $z= e^{i\theta}$ for $0\le \theta< 2\pi$.  So the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n} e^{n(n+1)i\theta}$

Comment: Now what can I do? Please help me.